# pop_back function in custom vector class

Tags: c++, oop, vector

So I've been looking at code from this website: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-create-custom-vector-class-in-c/. But I'm having a problem understanding this part:

```
template <typename DT>
DT GenericMyVector<DT>::pop_back()
{
    return arr[length-- - 1];
}
```

I understand that this lowers `int length` by one, and when you call function size it will be smaller by one. But here are my questions: What does  `- 1` do? Since arrays are fixed in size how does this lower the amount of memory taken up by the vector? And how exactly does the last element get popped back?

Comment: note that the code does not do a good job at demonstrating how a self-written vector could look like. For a moment I thought that I have to change my opinion of geeksforgeeks, but ignoring the [rule of 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for a custom vector implementation is a no go. I expect more problems in the details

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 do you by any chance know of any better examples out there of  these custom vector classes?

Comment: unfortunately no. Its not easy to keep it simple but not horribly broken at the same time. I wouldnt mind if they focus only on some aspects, but pretending that this is a usable vector is a bad joke. And the joke is on you, beginners coming to the page expecting to learn. Look here: https://godbolt.org/z/zda45fGfx. I removed a check at line131 to demonstrate what happens when I make a copy in line 173. I can then print elements in a vector that should not have any elements (line 181). The only reason there is no undefined behavior is because they decided to leak the vectors memory. It's sad

Comment: I happened to stop scrolling at `operator[]()`. This is nigh malicious it's so not good for learning. I've never trusted the site, but I've never seen anything this awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length--` evaluates to the value of length (decrementing after evaluation). So the item you're accessing is `arr[length - 1]`. You need the -1 because array indexes start at zero.

It's easier to think of the code as:

```cpp
template <typename DT>
DT GenericMyVector<DT>::pop_back()
{
    DT value = arr[length - 1];
    length--;
    return value;
}
```

Comment: And how does this affect the last element of the vector getting popped, and what goes on in memory once it gets popped?

Comment: @bb_823 So this `pop_back` function just "removes" the item from the vector by decrementing the length counter. The item itself still remains in the array. On the next `push_back` call that item in the array will be overwritten.

Comment: would it be efficient to delete the array and create the new one without the last element and smaller in size by one

Comment: @bb_823 It would not. Every time an array is deleted and replaced with a new one you're copying all the items in the array. Consider a vector with 100 items and you call pop_back on each one. You'll have to copy 99 items on the first pop, 98 items on the second, etc. All in all you'll perform 5000 copies. This is a lot of work! Now what about 1000 items? For that you'd copy half a million items. (look up "time complexity" and "big-O" notation if you are interested)

Comment: Take a look at the `push_back` function on that g4g tutorial. They avoid this large "time complexity" by doubling the size of the array whenever necessary. If you want to make your vector auto-shrink, consider cutting in half whenever the length is less than half the capacity.